# Sort objects in array by key with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, lodash

Hi Stack Overflow community!

I have the following test array:

```
let test = [{
    "searchQuery": "test",
    "resultsLoaded": -1,
    "offset": -1,
    "allResults": 10
}, {
    "metaData": {
        "type": "page-content",
        "image": true,
        "name": "lorem-ipsum",
        "rank": 10,
        "tags": ["website:lorem/ipsum"]
    },
    "componentData": {
        "header": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "path": "/content/asdf",
        "breadcrumbDouble": {
            "breadcrumbItem1": {
                "href": "lorem ipsum",
                "text": "lorem ipsum"
            },
            "breadcrumbItem2": {
                "href": "/content/asdf",
                "text": "Lorem Ipsum"
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "subheadline": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "img": {
                "alt": "",
                "imgSrc": "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg"
            },
            "tags": [{
                "category": "lorem",
                "value": "ipsum"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    "metaData": {
        "type": "page-content",
        "image": true,
        "name": "lorem-ipsum",
        "rank": 50,
        "tags": ["website:lorem/ipsum"]
    },
    "componentData": {
        "header": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "path": "/content/asdf",
        "breadcrumbDouble": {
            "breadcrumbItem1": {
                "href": "lorem ipsum",
                "text": "lorem ipsum"
            },
            "breadcrumbItem2": {
                "href": "/content/asdf",
                "text": "Lorem Ipsum"
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "subheadline": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "img": {
                "alt": "",
                "imgSrc": "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg"
            },
            "tags": [{
                "category": "lorem",
                "value": "ipsum"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    "metaData": {
        "type": "page-content",
        "image": true,
        "name": "lorem-ipsum",
        "rank": 30,
        "tags": ["website:lorem/ipsum"]
    },
    "componentData": {
        "header": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "path": "/content/asdf",
        "breadcrumbDouble": {
            "breadcrumbItem1": {
                "href": "lorem ipsum",
                "text": "lorem ipsum"
            },
            "breadcrumbItem2": {
                "href": "/content/asdf",
                "text": "Lorem Ipsum"
            }
        },
        "content": {
            "subheadline": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "img": {
                "alt": "",
                "imgSrc": "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg"
            },
            "tags": [{
                "category": "lorem",
                "value": "ipsum"
            }]
        }
    }
}];
```

What I want to achive now is to sort the objects by **`metaData.rank`** from highest to lowest.

I wanted to use lodash's `orderBy()` like this:

```
let result = orderBy(test, function(e) {
    let array = parseInt(e.metaData.rank);
    return array;
}, ['desc']);
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rank' of undefined

`console.log(e)` in my `orderBy` function shows me this:

```
{
    searchQuery: 'test',
    resultsLoaded: -1,
    offset: -1,
    allResults: 10
}
```

Any quick suggestions to fix this?

I know that the first object is causing the problem because of the different structure. So I need to work around it!

Comment: what is with the first entry? should it stay on top?

Comment: @NinaScholz In the best case, it should stay on top.

Comment: @mrks Is the different object always in the first position? Could be more of it in the same array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the items without `metaData` property to top and sort the rest by `rank`.

```js
var array = [{ searchQuery: "test", resultsLoaded: -1, offset: -1, allResults: 10 }, { metaData: { type: "page-content", image: true, name: "lorem-ipsum", rank: 10, tags: ["website:lorem/ipsum"] }, componentData: { header: "Lorem Ipsum", path: "/content/asdf", breadcrumbDouble: { breadcrumbItem1: { href: "lorem ipsum", text: "lorem ipsum" }, breadcrumbItem2: { href: "/content/asdf", text: "Lorem Ipsum" } }, content: { subheadline: "Lorem Ipsum", img: { alt: "", imgSrc: "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg" }, tags: [{ category: "lorem", value: "ipsum" }] } } }, { metaData: { type: "page-content", image: true, name: "lorem-ipsum", rank: 50, tags: ["website:lorem/ipsum"] }, componentData: { header: "Lorem Ipsum", path: "/content/asdf", breadcrumbDouble: { breadcrumbItem1: { href: "lorem ipsum", text: "lorem ipsum" }, breadcrumbItem2: { href: "/content/asdf", text: "Lorem Ipsum" } }, content: { subheadline: "Lorem Ipsum", img: { alt: "", imgSrc: "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg" }, tags: [{ category: "lorem", value: "ipsum" }] } } }, { metaData: { type: "page-content", image: true, name: "lorem-ipsum", rank: 30, tags: ["website:lorem/ipsum"] }, componentData: { header: "Lorem Ipsum", path: "/content/asdf", breadcrumbDouble: { breadcrumbItem1: { href: "lorem ipsum", text: "lorem ipsum" }, breadcrumbItem2: { href: "/content/asdf", text: "Lorem Ipsum" } }, content: { subheadline: "Lorem Ipsum", img: { alt: "", imgSrc: "/content/dam/production/images/asdf.jpeg.imgTransformer/listPageItem/desktop/1511962617778/asdf.jpg" }, tags: [{ category: "lorem", value: "ipsum" }] } } }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    return ('metaData' in a) - ('metaData' in b) || b.metaData.rank - a.metaData.rank;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Do you have an idea how to adapt your solution to check first for the rank and if, for example, two objects have the same rank to order them by alphabet ```componentData.header```?

Comment: you could chain the next order criterium by using another logicla or at the end like `... || a.componentData.header > b.componentData.header || -(a.componentData.header < b.componentData.header)` for a sorting by alphabet (it works even for numbers as well).

Answer (score 1):

The first object in the array `test` is causing that problem. It doesn't have the same structure as the others. If `e` was that first object, then `e.metaData` is `undefined`.

I suggest you `shift` that first object, `sort` the array, then `unshift` it back to the sorted array:

```
let test = [...];

let first = test.shift();                                  // remove the first object from the array and store it in 'first'
test.sort((a, b) => b.metaData.rank - a.metaData.rank);    // sort the array (you can use orderBy here if you want)
test.unshift(first);                                       // unshift the first object (return it back to the first index of the array)
```

**Note:** The solution I suggested assumes there is only one different object and that this object always at the index `0`.

Comment: This doesn't seem extendable. What if that element is at a different index? Rest two answers seem to be working with all scenarios.

Comment: @31piy I don't think that object could be at another position (it is a header object that describes the others). I'll ask OP for more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

instead `e.metaData.rank` use:

```
_.get(e, ['metaData', 'rank'], /*value if rank field is not exist*/ -1);
```